# i am not able to get any alert(data.title); $(document).ready() is working fine

Tags: jquery, json

I am not able to parse the json data by the following code, its not even giving any alert please tell me where i have mistaken 
when i am using the json content in an array then no issues are there but when i am attaching it to a file nothing haapens

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("dat.js",function(data){
            $.each(data.posts,function(i,data){
                alert(data.title);
            });
        });

});
```

my json file is

```
{

"posts": 
[
{ 
"title":"ajax | Programming ", 
"url":"hello" 
}, 
{ 
"title":"jQuery and Ajax Demos Pard - 3", 
"url":"how are you"
}, 
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct (check http://jsfiddle.net/mX4E2/) so the problem must  be that your file is not reached by `$.getJSON`. Have you checked with firebug that the call is correct?

EDIT - remove the last  comma from the json, otherwise IE will complain

Answer (score 2):

your json is malformed (and this, unfortunately, causes silent errors). You have to remove last comma

check it with jslint : http://www.jslint.com/

this is the code cleaned

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "title":"ajax | Programming ",
    "url":"hello"
  },
  {
    "title":"jQuery and Ajax Demos Pard - 3",
    "url":"how are you"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your JSON content correctly loaded by the JavaScript. Did you check that in your browsers inspector? Try console.log(data); before and within the each block.

fabrizio-calderan is right!

Answer (score 1):

make sure youre serving the file from a webserver (it just makes testing easy'er).
and try to flatten youre json file so it dont containe the newline and tab symbols etc. and remove the last comma in the post array (you shod only use comma to seperate to objects not to show the array is ending)

also dubbel check the file url :)

Comment: when i am using the json content in an array then no issues are there but when i am attaching it to a file nothing haapens

Comment: you have alot of linebreaks and new lines in youre JSON, personaly i seen parsers go banans over it. also when youre typing youre array make sure you dont have a comma after the last item in the array (youre sample code shows this)